# Out of memory error exception while running a Deep Learning python code

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to run the Deep Image Prior's Super Resolution. While running it, I am getting this error. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong ? I am using CUDA-9.2, GPU 12GB which are sufficient to run this code. Someone told me to reduce the batch size and I don't know how to do it. I am new to this.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import argparse
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'

import numpy as np
from models import *

import torch
import torch.optim

from skimage.measure import compare_psnr
from models.downsampler import Downsampler

from utils.sr_utils import *

torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark =True
dtype = torch.cuda.FloatTensor

imsize = -1 
factor = 4 # 8
enforse_div32 = 'CROP' # we usually need the dimensions to be divisible by a power of two (32 in this case)
PLOT = True

# To produce images from the paper we took *_GT.png images from LapSRN viewer for corresponding factor,
# e.g. x4/zebra_GT.png for factor=4, and x8/zebra_GT.png for factor=8 
path_to_image = '/home/smitha/Documents/Falcon.png'
imgs = load_LR_HR_imgs_sr(path_to_image , imsize, factor, enforse_div32)

imgs['bicubic_np'], imgs['sharp_np'], imgs['nearest_np'] = get_baselines(imgs['LR_pil'], imgs['HR_pil'])

if PLOT:
    plot_image_grid([imgs['HR_np'], imgs['bicubic_np'], imgs['sharp_np'], imgs['nearest_np']], 4,12);
    print ('PSNR bicubic: %.4f   PSNR nearest: %.4f' %  (
                                        compare_psnr(imgs['HR_np'], imgs['bicubic_np']), 
                                        compare_psnr(imgs['HR_np'], imgs['nearest_np'])))
input_depth = 32

INPUT =     'noise'
pad   =     'reflection'
OPT_OVER =  'net'
KERNEL_TYPE='lanczos2'

LR = 0.01
tv_weight = 0.0

OPTIMIZER = 'adam'

if factor == 4: 
    num_iter = 2000
    reg_noise_std = 0.03
elif factor == 8:
    num_iter = 4000
    reg_noise_std = 0.05
else:
    assert False, 'We did not experiment with other factors'
net_input = get_noise(input_depth, INPUT, (imgs['HR_pil'].size[1], imgs['HR_pil'].size[0])).type(dtype).detach()

NET_TYPE = 'skip' # UNet, ResNet
net = get_net(input_depth, 'skip', pad,
              skip_n33d=128, 
              skip_n33u=128, 
              skip_n11=4, 
              num_scales=5,
              upsample_mode='bilinear').type(dtype)

# Losses
mse = torch.nn.MSELoss().type(dtype)

img_LR_var = np_to_torch(imgs['LR_np']).type(dtype)

downsampler = Downsampler(n_planes=3, factor=factor, kernel_type=KERNEL_TYPE, phase=0.5, preserve_size=True).type(dtype)
def closure():
    global i, net_input

    if reg_noise_std > 0:
        net_input = net_input_saved + (noise.normal_() * reg_noise_std)

    out_HR = net(net_input)
    out_LR = downsampler(out_HR)

    total_loss = mse(out_LR, img_LR_var) 

    if tv_weight > 0:
        total_loss += tv_weight * tv_loss(out_HR)

    total_loss.backward()

    # Log
    psnr_LR = compare_psnr(imgs['LR_np'], torch_to_np(out_LR))
    psnr_HR = compare_psnr(imgs['HR_np'], torch_to_np(out_HR))
    print ('Iteration %05d    PSNR_LR %.3f   PSNR_HR %.3f' % (i, psnr_LR, psnr_HR), '\r', end='')

    # History
    psnr_history.append([psnr_LR, psnr_HR])

    if PLOT and i % 100 == 0:
        out_HR_np = torch_to_np(out_HR)
        plot_image_grid([imgs['HR_np'], imgs['bicubic_np'], np.clip(out_HR_np, 0, 1)], factor=13, nrow=3)

    i += 1

    return total_loss
psnr_history = [] 
net_input_saved = net_input.detach().clone()
noise = net_input.detach().clone()

i = 0
p = get_params(OPT_OVER, net, net_input)
optimize(OPTIMIZER, p, closure, LR, num_iter)
out_HR_np = np.clip(torch_to_np(net(net_input)), 0, 1)
result_deep_prior = put_in_center(out_HR_np, imgs['orig_np'].shape[1:])

# For the paper we acually took `_bicubic.png` files from LapSRN viewer and used `result_deep_prior` as our result
plot_image_grid([imgs['HR_np'],
                 imgs['bicubic_np'],
                 out_HR_np], factor=4, nrow=1);
```

The Error is :

```
Starting optimization with ADAM

/home/smitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/upsampling.py:122: UserWarning: nn.Upsampling is deprecated. Use nn.functional.interpolate instead.
  warnings.warn("nn.Upsampling is deprecated. Use nn.functional.interpolate instead.")
/home/smitha/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1961: UserWarning: Default upsampling behavior when mode=bilinear is changed to align_corners=False since 0.4.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details.
  "See the documentation of nn.Upsample for details.".format(mode))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0fe781a02812> in <module>()
      5 i = 0
      6 p = get_params(OPT_OVER, net, net_input)
----> 7 optimize(OPTIMIZER, p, closure, LR, num_iter)

~/Documents/deep-image-prior/utils/common_utils.py in optimize(optimizer_type, parameters, closure, LR, num_iter)
    227         for j in range(num_iter):
    228             optimizer.zero_grad()
--> 229             closure()
    230             optimizer.step()
    231     else:

<ipython-input-5-887ba7755977> in closure()
      5         net_input = net_input_saved + (noise.normal_() * reg_noise_std)
      6 
----> 7     out_HR = net(net_input)
      8     out_LR = downsampler(out_HR)
      9 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     89     def forward(self, input):
     90         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 91             input = module(input)
     92         return input
     93 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     89     def forward(self, input):
     90         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 91             input = module(input)
     92         return input
     93 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    299     def forward(self, input):
    300         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 301                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    302 
    303 

RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory
```

If I reduce the size of the input image I get this error.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0fe781a02812> in <module>()
      5 i = 0
      6 p = get_params(OPT_OVER, net, net_input)
----> 7 optimize(OPTIMIZER, p, closure, LR, num_iter)

~/Documents/deep-image-prior/utils/common_utils.py in optimize(optimizer_type, parameters, closure, LR, num_iter)
    227         for j in range(num_iter):
    228             optimizer.zero_grad()
--> 229             closure()
    230             optimizer.step()
    231     else:

<ipython-input-5-887ba7755977> in closure()
      8     out_LR = downsampler(out_HR)
      9 
---> 10     total_loss = mse(out_LR, img_LR_var)
     11 
     12     if tv_weight > 0:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    475             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    476         else:
--> 477             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    478         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    479             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py in forward(self, input, target)
    419 
    420     def forward(self, input, target):
--> 421         return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
    422 
    423 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in mse_loss(input, target, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   1714     else:
   1715         reduction = _Reduction.get_enum(reduction)
-> 1716     return _pointwise_loss(lambda a, b: (a - b) ** 2, torch._C._nn.mse_loss, input, target, reduction)
   1717 
   1718 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in _pointwise_loss(lambd, lambd_optimized, input, target, reduction)
   1672         return torch.mean(d) if reduction == 'elementwise_mean' else torch.sum(d)
   1673     else:
-> 1674         return lambd_optimized(input, target, reduction)
   1675 
   1676 

RuntimeError: input and target shapes do not match: input [1 x 3 x 64 x 64], target [1 x 1 x 64 x 64] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1532502421238/work/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/MSECriterion.cu:12
```

Comment: what's the size of your input image?

Comment: It is about (750, 750)

Comment: have you tried with a smaller image?

Comment: I have then I got a different error. It says that the input and target shapes do not match

Comment: It looks like the `(750, 750)` you have is too big for your GPU RAM. As for the other error, I can't really help you if you don't post the stack trace and show where the error generated in the code. Was the dimension of the image you used divisible by a power of 2?

Comment: Will post the trace back. And the GPU is 12 GB  (Also, I am using a cluster) which is sufficient. I don't know where I am going wrong!!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the model, but intermediate feature maps might be very big for an image that size and the RAM not sufficient. As for the other error, it looks like the target is a greyscale image, while your image is RGB.

Comment: I am new to this. How can I change it to Greyscale? I tried to convert it to greyscale but still getting the same error.

Comment: can you provide me a link for the image that raises the `RuntimeError: input and target shapes do not match`?

Comment: I made a silly mistake here n_channels=1. Now, it's solved. Thank you!

Comment: hey @JamesGrey, i'm running into same issue of `RuntimeError: input and target shapes do not match` using similar code, how did you solve it?  i don't see a n_channels=1?

Comment: Ok i added n_channels to get_net call, but now i get: `Given groups=1, weight of size [3, 3, 16, 16], expected input[1, 1, 172, 268] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead`